# PHP - Deleting folder/files only if there are no more in there

Tags: php, file, unlink

`$value` can = a folder structure to the language file.  Example:  languages/english.php

`$value` can also = the files name.  Example:  english.php

So I need to get the current folder that `$value` is in and delete the folder ONLY if there are no other files/folders within that directory (after deleting the actual file as I am doing already, ofcourse).

```
foreach($module['languages'] as $lang => $langFile)
{
        foreach ($langFile as $type => $value)
        {
            @unlink($module_path . '/' . $value);
            // Now I need to delete the folder ONLY if there are no other directories inside the folder where it is currently at.
            // And ONLY if there are NO OTHER files within that folder also.
        }
}
```

How can I do this??  And wondering if this can be done without using a while loop, since a `while` loop within a `foreach` loop could take some time, and need this to be as quick as possible.

And just FYI, the $module_path should never be deleted.  So if `$value = english.php`, it should never delete the $module_path.  Ofcourse, there will always be another file in there, so checking for this is not necessary, but won't hurt either way.

Thanks guys :)

**EDIT**

Ok, now I'm using this code here and it is NOT working, it is not removing the folders or the files, and I don't get any errors either... so not sure what the problem is here:

```
foreach($module['languages'] as $lang => $langFile)
{
    foreach ($langFile as $type => $value)
    {
        if (@unlink($module_path . '/' . $value))
            @rmdir(dirname($module_path . '/' . $value));
    }
}
```

NEVERMIND, this works a CHARM!!!  Cheers Everyone!!

Comment: [Symfony's Finder component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/tools/finder.html) (see also this [post](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/43/find-your-files) on Fabien's blog) makes it really easy to do find and traverse directories and files. It might be an overkill for that specific case, and I'm not 100% sure it does what you've asked for - but its might be worth mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the directory you care about might be part of the `$value`, you need to use `dirname` to figure out what the parent directory is, you can't just assume that it's `$module_path`.

```
$file_path = $module_path . '/' . $value;

if (@unlink($file_path)) {
    @rmdir(dirname($file_path));
}
```

Comment: Am trying to use the code you posted, seems simple enough, but it is not working, any reason why??  The exact code I'm using is in my original question at the bottom of it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The easyest way is try to use `rmdir`. This don't delete folder if it is not empty

```
rmdir($module_path);
```

also you can check is folder empty by

```
if(count(glob($module_path.'*'))<3)//delete
```

2 for `.` and `..`

**UPD**: as I reviewed maybe you should replace $module_path by dirname($module_path.'.'.$value);

Comment: WOW, that's great to know.  Didn't know that `rmdir` had to have an empty folder for it to be able to delete it.  SWEET!!!

Comment: I updated it with the code I'm using for this, but it doesn't work, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_file($value)) { 
  unlink($value); 

} else if (is_dir($value)) {
  if  (count(scandir($value)) == 2) }
     unlink($value)  
  }
}
```

[http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is_dir.php)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 0):

The code below will take a path, check if it is a file (i.e. not a directory). If it is a file, it will extract the directory name, then delete the file, then iterate over the dir and count the files in it, if the files are zero it'll delete the dir.

Code is as an example and should work, however privileges and environment setup may result in it not working.

```
<?php

if(!is_dir ( string $filename )){ //if it is a file
    $fileDir = dirname ( $filename );
    if ($handle = opendir($fileDir)) {
        echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
        echo "Files:\n";
        $numFiles=0;

        //delete the file
        unlink($myFile);

        //Loop the dir and count the file in it
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $numFiles = $numFiles + 1;
        }

        if($numFiles == 0) { 
            //delete the dir
            rmdir($fileDir);
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
}
?>
```